# Favicon not working on my login page

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, favicon

I have a favicon on my website.  It does not show up when i go to my login page, but works perfectly after logging in.  I am using forms authentication on my website.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: Yeah i guess since you can't login anyways. [Here is the page](https://pilot.col.missouri.edu/oncall/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the favicon is in your root directory, most browsers should display it automatically.

I visited the page and did not receive a favicon (as you suggested) but checked the source and noticed you do not link to the favicon explicitly.  Try to add a line similar to the following in your own `<head>` section:

```
<link href='corbyhaas/favicon.ico' type='image/png' rel='icon' />
```

For more information, check out w3's [How To Favicon](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).

**Edit:** This is the source I see for the head tag in your login page.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/masterstyle.css" />
    <title>OnCall APP_ADMIN</title>
</head>
```

Obviously you're including the necessary information in the rest of your application; just do the same thing in whatever builds the `<head>` tag on the login page.

Comment: I already have that line in my masterpage in the head section.  I have also tried it in the images folder and the root directory.  Both ways do the same thing.

Comment: As it works perfectly after logging in, you're doing the right thing in your masterpage.  The bug is that however you're calling the link in the masterpage *isn't* being used by the login page.  There's no reference to a favicon anywhere in the source of that page.

Comment: You are correct.  My partner on this project build the login page and for some reason did not use the master page.  I now have the links added, but it still does not pull it.

Comment: <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/masterstyle.css" />
    <link href="../images/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"/>
    <link href="../images/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"></link>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"></link>

    <title>OnCall APP_ADMIN</title>
</head>